# Spyder won't connect to kernel / iPython console

Tags: python, spyder

Since my laptop crashed (for unknown reason) last night, Spyder has not been able to connect to a kernel. I am getting this error:

```
IOError: Could not find u'kernel-1809.json' in ['.', '~/Library/Jupyter/runtime']
```

(The name of the json file changes each time I attempt to launch an iPython console.)

This does not seem to be related to the matplotlib 1.5 issue, that I have seen elsewhere on here - it is using 1.4.3.

iPython (version 4.0.0) runs fine from the command line.

Mac 10.10.1 (Yosemite). Spyder 2.3.7. Python 2.7.10 64bits, Qt 4.8.7, PyQt4 (API v2) 4.11.3 on Darwin

**UPDATED TO INCLUDE LOGS**

```
>>> /Volumes/Spyder-Py2/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/nbformat/current.py:19: UserWarning: nbformat.current is deprecated.

- use nbformat for read/write/validate public API
- use nbformat.vX directly to composing notebooks of a particular version

ERROR: 3rd party plugin import failed for `p_pylint`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Spyder-Py2/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderlib/otherplugins.py", line 53, in get_spyderplugins_mods
  File "/Volumes/Spyder-Py2/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderplugins/p_pylint.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "/Volumes/Spyder-Py2/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderplugins/widgets/pylintgui.py", line 71, in <module>
  File "/Volumes/Spyder-Py2/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderplugins/widgets/pylintgui.py", line 61, in get_pylint_version
  File "subprocess.pyc", line 710, in __init__
  File "subprocess.pyc", line 1335, in _execute_child
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Spyder-Py2/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderlib/plugins/externalconsole.py", line 925, in <lambda>
give_focus=give_ipyclient_focus))
  File "/Volumes/Spyder-Py2/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderlib/plugins/externalconsole.py", line 1033, in register_ipyclient
give_focus=give_focus)
  File "/Volumes/Spyder-Py2/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderlib/plugins/ipythonconsole.py", line 836, in register_client
self.connect_client_to_kernel(client)
  File "/Volumes/Spyder-Py2/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderlib/plugins/ipythonconsole.py", line 1048, in connect_client_to_kernel
client.password)
  File "/Volumes/Spyder-Py2/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderlib/plugins/ipythonconsole.py", line 1017, in create_kernel_manager_and_client
cf = find_connection_file(connection_file)
  File "/Volumes/Spyder-Py2/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/jupyter_client/connect.py", line 185, in find_connection_file
raise IOError("Could not find %r in %r" % (filename, path))
IOError: Could not find u'kernel-2018.json' in ['.', u'/Users/garyspatterson/Library/Jupyter/runtime']
```

** Further update **

I deleted all files under the .spyder2/ folder in my user directory, reopened Spyder, and it was able to connect to an iPython console. So far, so good. Trouble is, when I added a path to the PYTHONPATH manager (so I could import external modules, such as nltk), I am back to getting the same error.

Comment: Appending some logs to your question would be nice.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. I am trying to have Spyder using a virtualenv with nltk, and getting the same error. Deleting ` .spyder2/` is not really a solution since it resets all Spyder settings and you are back to using the default interpreter. Have you made any progress on this?

Comment: @silentser - I wasn't ever able to figure it out.  This problem was occurring in Spyder which I had installed directly. I ended up installing Anaconda and using Spyder within this installation. Now there is no need to add paths to the PYTHONPATH manager, so it works OK. But I am still at a loss as to why the other Spyder just stopped working like that. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and was able to resolve it by creating a new virtualenv with the same dependencies installed.
Now Spyder is working with the `PYTHONPATH` pointing at `lib/python2.7/site-packages` of the new environment.